# Does Ubuntu 17.10 break the BIOS?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, 17.10

I'm considering to upgrade my PC to Ubuntu v17.10, but I'm afraid because there's a BIOS issue has been confirmed for several different lines of Lenovo laptops also the reports of it affecting a few Acer, Toshiba and Dell laptops.

Should I upgrade or not? Also I can't download the Latest Ubuntu 17.10 ISO, the official website download link is currently discouraged.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 is marked as fixed, so you should be safe.

Answer (score 32):

[Ubuntu 17.10.1 has been released to avoid that problem](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntu-17-10-1-download-iso-torrent-bios-fix/). Ensure that the installer you use is 17.10.1, not 17.10. The ISOs are available [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/).

Comment: The question was about *upgrade*. Upgrading should install all the latest updates to 17.10 though.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question stated in the title "Would the kernel included with 17.10 lock the BIOS into read-only?", it only says a workaround for the actual problem that is not even acknowledged. I recommend you edit it into your answer to prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: @Ferrybig As you can see by the edits, the question in the title wasn't the question in the title at the time I answered.