# Why was 17.10.1 released?

Tags: 17.10, release-management, point-release

I just noticed when going back through [the releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) that 17.10 was released as usual, but then 17.10.1 was subsequently released. This is not normal - the standard release cycle only has point releases for LTS versions (e.g. 14.04, 16.04, 18.04).

Why was this unusual point release made?

Comment: Related: [Does Ubuntu 17.10 break the BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/996014/301745)

Answer (score 6):

Shortly after release, [reports were received](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) of a bug in UEFI firmware of laptops from Lenovo, Acer, and Toshiba which  corrupted the BIOS and made the machine unbootable.

[In late December](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntu-17-10-1-download-iso-torrent-bios-fix/) the download links of Ubuntu 17.10 were removed from the website. Shortly after, a fixed version of Ubuntu was released as a point release - Ubuntu 17.10.1.

The issue was due to a bug in the Intel Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) kernel module.

The Q&A [Does Ubuntu 17.10 break the BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/996014/301745) may also be of interest.

My pronouns are He / Him